# How to change triangle 60 arrow head scale?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-arrows

I am using triangle 60 and Latex arrow styles. I change the scale of the Latex arrow using the following command:

```
-{Latex[length=5mm, width=2mm]}]
```

However, i can't change the triangle 60 arrow size with the same length, width attributes. Is there any other solution for this?

Comment: Please add a MWE to show us your exact problem (pictures are helpful too, if they are combined with a MWE).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to use the `Triangle` arrow tip from the `arrows.meta` library.

The old arrow tips such as `triangle 60` does not allow for the customizations that you can do with the new ones from `arrows.meta`. The ones from `arrows.meta` have names that start with capital latters (e.g. `Latex`), whereas the old ones start with lower case letters (e.g. `latex`), so they are easily distinguished.

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw [-{Triangle[length=3mm,width=5mm]}] (0,1) -- (2,1);
\draw [-{Triangle[angle=60:5mm]}] (0,0) -- (2,0);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```